# How do I make a programatically changed site dashboard refresh without restarting the Alfresco/Tomcat service?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I've created a web-script module extension and have verified that it works correctly. What it does is takes the `dashboard.xml` and related `page.component-X-Y.type~id~dashboard.xml` files from one site, deletes all dashboard related files on another site then copies the source files to the new site that had them deleted.

**pseudo-code**

```
var siteDashboard = getDashboard("site1-shortname");
var siteDashboard = renameShortNames("site1-shortname", "short2-shortname");

deleteDashboard("site2-shortname");
createDashboard("site2-shortname", siteDashboard);
```

`renameShortNames` just renames the site id inside the dashboard files to the new site's id.

This all works, I've tested and verified it. My problem is that when I go to `http://alfrescosite.com/alfresco/s/remoteadm/get/s/sitestore/alfresco/site-data/pages/site/site2-shortname/dashboard.xml` it shows me the new dashboard layout from `site1-shortname` which is the correct behavior but when I go to the actual site's dashboard within Alfresco share it shows the old `site2-shortname` dashboard. The only way I can get the new dashboard to show is by restarting the Alfresco/Tomcat service. I've even tried looking at the dashboard with a different browser just in case it was a local caching issue but it's not.

Any ideas on how to make the dashboards refresh to the new layout without having to restart the Alfresco/Tomcat service every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The problem was that I was deleting and recreating the dashboard via `Remote API` calls to the `Alfresco Repository` and doing it that way was making the appropriate changes but not telling `Alfresco Share` of those changes.

The solution was to use a combination the Share root object `sitedata` to remove the component bindings, delete the components and recreate them through `Share` so that the changes are automatically updated on the front end without the need for a service restart.

Basically this ended up being a modified version of the code in `customise-dashboard.post.json.js` inside `Alfresco Share`